# c++ access derived class with a pointer from base class

Tags: c++, pointers, derived

The compiler keeps saying `'class A' has no member named 'foo'.`
I am trying to use a function from a derived class with a pointer. Here is my code:

```
 class A{
  .....
};

class B:public A{
     virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class C:public B{
....
public:
    void foo(){
        ....
    }
};
```

I have a table of `A` pointers named `Table` and when trying

```
Table[j]->foo()
```

I am getting the compiler error.

What should I do except cast?

Comment: Move the pure virtual function to `A`? That's the type you actually try to use polymorphically.

Comment: Because class `A` does not have a member function named `foo()`.

Comment: but I don't want class B to have a foo() function

Comment: So don't define it in `B`. It won't have it.

Comment: If foo() goes to A then class B must have it too, right?

Comment: What gave you that idea?

Comment: If `A` declares `foo` as pure virtual then `B` can simply do nothing and leave the implementation of `foo` to `C`.

Comment: It's a pure virtual function so it has to be defined to the derived classes.

Comment: only for derived classes which must be *concrete* classes

Comment: @Jokk - No it doesn't. [Any good C++ book will tell you as much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Do you ever need an instance of `B`? Or is it just an abstract base?

Comment: Except cast? Redesign. You have an animal. You want it to bark. But it's a goldfish. What should happen?

Answer (score 2):

You have a compilation error because function `foo` is not declared in class `A`.

You can declare it as pure virtual in `A` like this:

```
class A {
     virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

In derived classes you don't have to declare `foo` as explicitly `virtual`. If only `C` is a concrete class, you don't have to declare `foo` in class `B` at all.

If your example if you know that in your array of pointers to `A` you have only instances of class C you can explicitly cast to pointer to `C` but it is a sign of poor design and I don't recommend it:

```
static_cast<C*>(Table[j])->foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pointer to a base and want to access a member of the derived type you have to cast so you have a pointer to the derived type, either that or as in your case add `foo()` as a virtual member to the base.

```
class A
{ ... };
class B : public A:{
{
public:
  virtual foo() { std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl; }
};
class C : public B
{
public:
  void foo() { std::cout << "C::foo" << std::endl;
};
...
A * arr[8];
for(int i = 0; 8>i; ++i)
  arr[i] = new C;
((B*)arr[0])->foo(); // will print "C::foo\n"
```

But if you added `virtual void foo() = 0;` to `A` then you could just do `arr[0]->foo()` and it would still print `C::foo`

Comment: "Aaarrrrrggghhh" at that C-style cast. There's no reason not to use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` here.